# Calling a parent directive's function in a child directive

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm trying to make a pane system in which elem.bind('change,...) on a child directive changes the "selected" parent directive: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/gc35fuUiJVUhHF4QMAwv?p=preview

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('docsTabsExample', [])
    .directive('myTabs', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope) {
          var panes = $scope.panes = [];

          $scope.select = function(pane) {
            angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
              pane.selected = false;
            });
            pane.selected = true;
          };
          $scope.next = function(pane) {
            select(panes[panes.indexOf(pane)+1]);
          };
          this.addPane = function(pane) {
            if (panes.length === 0) {
              $scope.select(pane);
            }
            panes.push(pane);
          };
        },
        templateUrl: 'my-tabs.html'
      };
    })
    .directive('myPane', function() {
      return {
        require: '^myTabs',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          title: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
          tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
        },
        templateUrl: 'my-pane.html'
      };
    })
    .directive('pf-data', function() {
      return {
        require: '^myPane',
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
          title: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
          console.log("hi");
          element.bind('change', function() {
            scope.next();
            console.log("switch panes");
          });
        }
      };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

(When you pick gender (either male or female), I want it to go to the next pane in succession, but I assume due to scope issues (i'm fairly rusty with angular), that it never gets into the linked attribute of the child directive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of your directives defines an isolated scope (it's pretty much empty except for the contents of the `scope` member of the directive definition.  So when you are saying `scope.next()`, it's going to fail if it isn't either in this collection, or explicitly attached by the `link` function.  So using `$scope` to get to your parents isn't going to work.  And you certainly don't want to be leak internal details by passing functions down through the attributes.  That would kind of defeat the point of having these linked directives.

*But you have something even better.*

Because you are using `require` to link your directives together, you don't even have to bother with those games.  Within `pf-data`, you will define:

```
require: ['^myPane', '^myTabs]
```

This will give you direct access to both controllers.  You'll need to expose `next` on the `myTabs` directive.  Honestly, I'd figure out a way to use indices rather than loop through all of your panes setting true and false.  Something like:

```
var currentPane;
this.next = function() {
  select(nextPane(currentPane));
};
```

And now, within pf-data, you have access through your `link` function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      element.bind('change', function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          ctrls[1].next();
          scope.next();
        };
      });
  ...
```

**Update**

I forked a new Plnkr from the one you provided to incorporate the changes we've talked about.  I also dropped the require `myPane` from `pf-data` (which wouldn't have worked anyway because of the `transclude`).

http://plnkr.co/edit/LP0RYu6AKxeKyhHY5rZP?p=preview

Updates include:

- `pf-data` was changed to `pfData` -- it's just one of those rules of angular.  Your directives are named using camel case, but end up as hyphen-case in your html.
- I implemented all the little things I talked about.  `scope.$apply` and changing the `require` to use `myTabs`.  As we discussed in the comments, you need to use `$apply` whenever you are capturing events that aren't directly part of angular in order to signal the elements on the screen to update.
- I rebound all of your methods in `myTabs` to be on `this` instead of `$scope`.  You'll need them there since you are going at them through the controller mechanism.
- I maintain the currently selected pane in the controller so that we can just say `next()` without having to supply a pane.

Comment: @Michael_Hays set up the example so that it was using the updated requires and scope apply functions: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gc35fuUiJVUhHF4QMAwv?p=preview) The example is modified from the AngularJS docs on Directives.

Also can you explain why you can't just do ctrls[1].next(), why it has to be applied to both scopes, and why you have to do $scope.$apply.

Comment: You don't need both scopes at all -- you only need the one I added, but I didn't want to reduce the functionality that was already present in the event you needed the controller of `myPane`.  As for the `$scope.$apply` -- When external events are fired, they originate outside the angular architecture, and so they won't trigger any binds that you may have set up -- your view won't update.  Angular provides `$apply`-wrapped handlers for some cases, `ng-click`, et al, but only if you attach those handlers using angular's directives.  It's something that bites all of us from time to time.

Comment: Let me check out your example and make sure it's working.  I'll be back.

Comment: I updated my answer to incorporate the Plnkr you gave me.  It didn't have the changes I had talked about, so maybe you gave me an older version?  No matter, it should all work now.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct - this is a scope issue.  When you use isolated scope, the only scope variables that are available in your directives isolated scope from the parent scope, are the ones you pass in through attributes.  To call next() which is defined on parent scope inside of your directive, pass the method through an attribute with '&' binding:

```
  scope: {
       title:'@',
       next: '&'
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <my-pane next="next()"></my-pane>
```

Comment: I tried your solution [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gc35fuUiJVUhHF4QMAwv?p=preview) but I still don't see the functionality working.